# How does NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask work?

Tags: android, back-stack, android-navigation

please what is actuall behavior of this method? I thought that when bind this method call to my actionbar back button and also set the homepageactivity name in Manifest.xml, it should be then opened after the click in the button - regardless of the current task stack..
For example, when I open my Activity from widget, the parent Activity is not in BackStack - this is what I want to solve..I know I can somehow build my own taskstack, but I just thought, that this should be prebaked solution, shouldn't be? Right now it sends me back to the homescreen..
This is where I call it..the code is located in `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
 case android.R.id.home: 
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            //finish();
            return true;
```

Comment: "For example, when I open my Activity from widget, the parent is Activity is not in BackStack". Your navigate to your current activity without having the parent activity(home activity of your app) on backstack. pls check this http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.java

Comment: Ok, I got it now..I should add that myself..
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: So it works for me on Android 4.0.3, but does not on 4.3..
I have this in manifest.xml
 `<activity
            android:logo="@drawable/lion"
            android:name="cz.cvut.kosapp.components.people.PeopleActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="cz.cvut.kosapp.main.HomePageActivity"

            android:label="@string/profiles">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="cz.cvut.kosapp.main.HomePageActivity" />`

Comment: The NavUtils has a bug on android 4.1+, simply it doesn’t work. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58520

Comment: Well..they are kidding, right? When lower than JELLY_BEAN you have to use fallback solution, otherwise there is a bug and it does not work at all..
Anyway thanks..I need a shot now:)